# Custom options dropdown switch product

Tags: custom-options, select, selection

Is there a way to add a dropdown to a simple product, that's giving alternative products and when selecting, it navigates to that product?

For example I have the following product:

```
Apple iPad Pro 128GB Wi-Fi 12.9'' - Gold
```

I want to add a dropdown with the values, to switch to that product:

```
Apple iPad Pro 128GB Wi-Fi 12.9'' - Silver
Apple iPad Pro 128GB Wi-Fi 12.9'' - Space Grey
```

Each of these values are unique simple products, with there own SKU.

When selecting a dropdown value, I want to redirect the page to that specific product.

Is that possible with simple products and how?

Comment: Do you have any link between these products? like how do you define which products to show in dropdown?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I want to define that in a specifc way in the backend, for example the same way as selecting upsell/crossell.

Comment: Then its simple that you create a dropdown with all Linked products and use Javascript to redirect on dropdown value change.